# How to have a different input/output audio source

Tags: audio, bluetooth-audio, audio-controls

I have a one plus pro 8. It has excellent microphone (output) noise cancelling. I also have a Bose quiet comfort 35 II which has excellent noise (input) cancelling as well.

My problem is they when I ride the bus and talk to people:

1. If I use the phone default speaker they can hear me great but I cannot hear them
2. If I use the bose speaker then I hear them great but they don't hear me

Question: how can I speak using the phone microphone (output) but listen (input) using my Bose earphones?

Comment: I don't have an answer but Android's lack of support for sensible audio device selection (as on Windows for example) gobsmacks me. Cone on Google, put some of those development dollars towards something that affects lots of people lots of the time.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have an Android phone, you can use [Lesser AudioSwitch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nordskog.LesserAudioSwitch), an Android app found on the Play Store that allows you to switch between input and output for microphone and headphones both connected via Bluetooth or wires.

Comment: For some reason this app isn't compatible with my device

Comment: My phone is android 11